# Async onClick event return value from popup

Tags: javascript, async-await

EDIT2: I fixed the issue, as I was suspecting my whole approach was wrong. I did it by creating a second separate event with jQuery and just trigger it when the done button is clicked

```
$(selector).click(() => {
    Numpad.activate(document.getElementById(element));
});

$(selector).on("val-updated", (event, data) => {
    SendData(name, data)
});
```

And the done function:

```
done: () => {
    $(selector).trigger("val-updated", val);
}
```

EDIT: My whole approach seems to be wrong, as the done() method is both attached to the button that activates the numpad and the done button itself, but the done button itself is out of the onclick event of the button that opens the numpad. The done event sets the input value to the variable Numpad.val, is there a way to run the second row of code from my .click function only when Numpad.val is populated? Is there a way to add some sort of a trigger to do that? Like:

```
$("#someIdSelector").click(async () => {
    // This should execute as soon as the button is clicked and it does
    Numpad.activate(document.getElementById("#someIdSelector"));

    // This should execute only after Numpad.val gets a new value
    // which happens when the person clicks on the done button
    // and that runs the Numpad.done() function, which sets the value of Numpad.val
    SendData(name, Numpad.val);
});
```

I have a popup that is basically a numpad, where the user inputs some number and it has a button "done".

I have two functions (concerning my issue) about the popup, I have an **activate** function and **done** function.

Then I have a third function that is attaching the onClick code to a button, it handles the activation of the numpad and it should also receive the value from the numpad. The problem is that one of these operations is instantaneous, the other isn't. The code looks something like this:

Functions for the Numpad:

```
Numpad: {
    val: null,

    activate: () => {
      $("#btnTrigger").click();
    },

    done() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Numpad.val = $("#easy-numpad-output").text();
        $("#btnTrigger").click();
        Numpad.clear();

        resolve(Numpad.val);
    });
}
```

And in my onclick function I have, and this is where the problem is I am guessing:

```
$("#someIdSelector").click(async () => {
    // This should execute as soon as the button is clicked and it does
    Numpad.activate(document.getElementById("#someIdSelector"));

    // This should execute only when Numpad.done() is resolved (when the user pressed done on the numpad)
    SendData(name, await Numpad.done());
});
```

Instead what is happening is that all of the code inside the onclick is getting executed as soon as I click on a button, and of course at that point Numpad.done() is undefined. I also tried with .then, but the console.log("Inside promise resolve") gets immediatelly called as soon as I press a button:

```
$("#someIdSelector").click(async () => {
    // This should execute as soon as the button is clicked and it does
    Numpad.activate(document.getElementById("#someIdSelector"));

    // This should execute only when Numpad.done() is resolved (when the user pressed done on the numpad)        
    Numpad.done().then((data) => {
        console.log("Inside promise resolve");
        SendData(name, data);

    });
});
```

Comment: Can't you use it that way: `await Numpad.done();  SendData(name);` ? So it only fires after the Numpad is finished?

Comment: Can you add the code in `// Some code to get the number into Numpad.val`? The reason the promise is being resolved before than intended should be in that portion of code.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd say there should be a callback/promise waiting for the user to press a button, but I don't see that callback/promise in the code. The `done()` promise should resolve only after that callback is called/promise is resolved

Comment: @pdpino I added the code, seems like it gets resolved twice, once when I click the button that opens the numpad, and then it also resolves when I click the done button. I have tried removing async from done, didnt help. Also, even tho it is resolving twice, neither of the times does it actually return the value of Numpad.val

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, I think my entire approach is wrong, because this way I have done() attached to two buttons, once in the button that activates the numpad (where im trying to do the async thing) and once on the done button itself. That is why it gets resolved twice probably.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a method as `async`, it *implicitly* returns a `Promise` once the first `await` is hit.

Your `done` method doesn't contain any `await` statements, so it immediately returns a `Promise` that is already resolved, the result of which is your unresolved `Promise`.

If you're returning a `Promise` manually, remove the `async` keyword; that way you will be awaiting that `Promise` when you `await Numpad.done()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, seems like that is kinda my issue, the promise gets resolved twice, once when a button that opens the numpad is clicked, and once on done click, but removing the async keyword did not help, it still resolves twice. Also even on the second resolve, it is not returning the value of Numpad.val.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, I think my entire approach is wrong, because this way I have done() attached to two buttons, once in the button that activates the numpad (where im trying to do the async thing) and once on the done button itself. That is why it gets resolved twice probably.